# Spring Boot JPA custom query suddenly stopped working

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So this is frustrating, i went about testing a session system i was implementing, I only worked with session variables, did NOT change anything in my database, my models or my repositories and all of a sudden JPA just stopped recognizing my table. I got the following error :

> Unknown column 't' in 'field list'

and when i change the custom query to use the table i get

> Unknown table '**_dev.ticket'

This is really wierd. everything worked fine, it just stopped working. i did not even restart the debugging session.

For more reference here is my repository code for this function:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select t.*, s.name as status, agent.name_surname as assigned, CAST(t.dt_created as VARCHAR(20)) as created from ticket t left join ticket_agent ta on t.id = ta.ticket_id and ta.active = true left join web_users agent on agent.id = ta.agent_id inner join ticket_status ts on t.id = ts.ticket_id and ts.isset inner join status s on ts.status_id = s.id where t.logged_by_id = :clientId and (s.name like :searchStr or t.subject like :searchStr or CAST(t.dt_created as VARCHAR(16)) like :searchStr or (case when agent.name_surname is null then 'Unassigned' else agent.name_surname end) like :searchStr) group by id")
Page<Ticket> findClientTickets(@Param("clientId") long agent, @Param("searchStr") String name, Pageable pageable);
```

Here is my model :

```
@Entity(name = "ticket")
@Table(name = "ticket")
public class Ticket {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(nullable = false)
   private long id;
   @Column(nullable = false)
   private String subject;
   @Column(nullable = false, length = 512)
   private String description;
   @Column()
   private String affected;
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "logged_by_id", nullable = false)
   private WebUser loggedBy;
   @Column(length = 1024)
   private String resolution;
   @Column(name = "dt_created", nullable = false)
   private Date created;
   @Column(name = "dt_resolved")
   private Date Resolved;
   @Column(name = "dt_closed")
   private Date Closed;
   @OneToOne
   @JoinColumn()
   private Thread thread;
   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id")
   private List<TicketAgent> ticketAgent = new ArrayList<>();
   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id")
   private List<TicketStatus> ticketStatus = new ArrayList<>();
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
   private ServiceType service;
   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id")
   private List<TicketAttachment> ticketAttachment = new ArrayList<>();
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn()
   private ClientAddress address;
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn()
   private SLA sla;
   @Column(name = "is_billable", nullable = false)
   private boolean isBillable;
   @Column(name = "is_onsite", nullable = false)
   private boolean isOnsite;
   @Column(nullable = false)
   private int priority;
   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id")
   private List<TicketNote> notes = new ArrayList<>();
   public Ticket(){
   }
   public long getId(){
       return this.id;
   }
   public String getSubject(){
       return this.subject;
   }
   public String getDescription(){
       return this.description;
   }
   public String getAffected(){
       return this.affected;
   }
   public WebUser getLoggedBy(){
       return this.loggedBy;
   }
   public String getResolution(){
       return this.resolution;
   }
   public Date getResolved(){
       return this.Resolved;
   }
   public Date getClosed(){
       return this.Closed;
   }
   public Thread getThread(){
       return this.thread;
   }
   public List<TicketAgent> getTicketAgent(){
       return this.ticketAgent;
   }
   public List<TicketStatus> getTicketStatus(){
       return this.ticketStatus;
   }
   public ServiceType getService(){
       return this.service;
   }
   public List<TicketAttachment> getTicketAttachment(){
       return this.ticketAttachment;
   }
   public ClientAddress getAddress(){
       return this.address;
   }
   public SLA getSla(){
       return this.sla;
   }
   public boolean isBillable(){
       return this.isBillable;
   }
   public boolean isOnsite(){
       return this.isOnsite;
   }
   public int getPriority(){
       return this.priority;
   }
   public List<TicketNote> getNotes(){
       return this.notes;
   }
   public void setSubject(String subject){
       this.subject = subject;
   }

   public void setDescription(String description){
       this.description = description;
   }

   public void setAffected(String affected){
       this.affected = affected;
   }

   public void setLoggedBy(WebUser loggedBy){
       this.loggedBy = loggedBy;
   }

   public void setResolution(String resolution){
       this.resolution = resolution;
   }

   public void setResolved(Date Resolved){
       this.Resolved = Resolved;
   }

   public void setClosed(Date Closed){
       this.Closed = Closed;
   }

   public void setThread(Thread thread){
       this.thread = thread;
   }

   public void setService(ServiceType service){
       this.service = service;
   }

   public void setAddress(ClientAddress address){
       this.address = address;
   }

   public void setSla(SLA sla){
       this.sla = sla;
   }

   public void setIsBillable(boolean isBillable){
       this.isBillable = isBillable;
   }

   public void setIsOnsite(boolean isOnsite){
       this.isOnsite = isOnsite;
   }

   public void setPriority(int priority){
       this.priority = priority;
   }

   public void setNotes(List<TicketNote> notes){
       this.notes = notes;
   }

//CODE_START

   public void addAttachment(String filepath) {
       TicketAttachment ticketAttachment = new TicketAttachment(this, filepath);
       if (this.ticketAttachment == null) {
           this.ticketAttachment = new ArrayList<>();
       }
       this.ticketAttachment.add(ticketAttachment);
   }

   public TicketStatus getStatus() {
       long maxDate = 0;
       TicketStatus mostRecentTicketStatus = null;

       for (TicketStatus ticketStatus : this.ticketStatus) {
           long time = ticketStatus.getCreated().getTime();
           if (time > maxDate && ticketStatus.isSet()) {
               maxDate = time;
               mostRecentTicketStatus = ticketStatus;
           }
       }
       return mostRecentTicketStatus;
   }

   public String getTicketClass() {
       TicketStatus latestTicket = getStatus();

       if (latestTicket == null) {
           return "badge badge-warning";
       }

       Status status = latestTicket.getStatus();
       int id = status.getColor();

       switch (id) {
           case 0:
               return "badge badge-info";
           case 1:
               return "badge badge-danger";
           case 2:
               return "badge badge-primary";
           case 3:
               return "badge badge-success";
           default:
               return "badge badge-success";
       }
   }

   public String getCreated() {
       SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd : HH:mm");
       return simpleDateFormat.format(created);
   }

   public WebUser getAgent() {
       for (TicketAgent agent : ticketAgent) {
           if (agent.isActive())
               return agent.getAgent();
       }
       return null;
   }

   public boolean hasAgent(){
       return getAgent() != null;
   }

   public void create() {
       if (this.created == null)
           this.created = new Date();
   }

}
```

Can anyone please explain to me how this can happen and maybe why?
The table does exist in the database, if i copy and paste the raw sql I also get a valid result from the database(OUTSIDE SPRING BOOT and JPA)

I might be stupid now, but im unable to find anything that closely resembles my problem.
I would've understood if i changed something in the database, model or repository but i did not.

It literally just started to appear.

Am i doing something wrong? Please help.

********UPDATE***********

If i log in as another user everything just magically works again even though i use the exact same parameters....
This has to be a caching issue. can anyone tell me how i can clear ALL the cache, tomcat included.

Comment: So i kind of figured out what is wrong. JPA is not picking up my wildcard anymore. Im going to try and add all the fields manually now.

Comment: Nope it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i still dont know what the problem was, if anyone knows please do let me know. this is very strange. it seems like the database or JPA got corrupted some how, i had to drop the entire database and it seems to work now for some reason. Once again if anyone knows how i could prevent this in the future please do let me know because im worried now what will happen if i go live with this application.

*****UPDATE*******
So i figured out it was a caching problem, and for some reason when i ran mvn clean in the terminal it did not work properly, so what i had to do was manually go to the maven tab and run the clean lifecycle, this solved alot of wierd things going on, i feel stupid for not realizing this earlier.